# I can`t call the bool function in c++ (closed)

Tags: c++, function, boolean

Hey guys please help me on this I have tried calling my bool function in my main func but it wont even show the first cout of program and the compiler terminates the program here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool puzzle(int size, int array[], int start)
{
    cout <<"how many blocks you want for the puzzle? \n";
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter your numbers in order for the blocks:\n";
            cin >> array[i];
            if (array[0] > size) { return false; };
            if (array[0] == size) { return true; };
    }
}

int main()
{

      puzzle;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given whatever source you're using to learn this language (whether it's a professor, tutorial website, or book), how do they teach you to call functions?

Comment: There are multiple issues with your program. I suggest you start by writing something simpler, e.g. a function called from `main` that only only prints `Hello world!` and nothing else. Do you know how you would do that?

Comment: You need to pass information to your function when you call it.  This is called a parameter list.  Review the section of your favorite C++ reference on how to call functions.

Comment: actually I have not seen sth like this type of function im using before i used to call void functions like "puzzle()"  but if use this it says too few arguments and i cant run the program

Comment: `puzzle;` does not call your function. Your function takes 3 arguments. You provide none.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @makankananian Please add information about what you tried (and what the errors/problems were) to the question. As it is right now it seems that you don't know how to call functions at all (e.g. `puzzle()`), but really you know that but have a different problem going by the comments. Also add what you intend `puzzle` to do. What is the return value supposed to be used for, etc...

Comment: @makankananian "_before i used to call void functions like "puzzle()" but if use this it says too few arguments and i cant run the program_" How many arguments does `puzzle` have? How many are you passing with `puzzle()`?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius oh so i have to use cin in my main function and pass the arguments to the bool one? and how i can do it with that array in the middle actually it does not have any value and i want the user to declare it

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius tnx I just get it now it was a stupid mistake tnx for the help <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has parameters so you need to call them to make it work. In this case (an example):

```
int size = 5;
int array[5];
int start = 0;

puzzle(size, array, start);
```